# Figure environment not compiling onto pdf

Tags: floats, captions

I'm trying to get the following image to show up in my document:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{experimentalapparatus}
\caption{Experimental Apparatus. Copied from Dr. Wes Campbell's Lab Manual.}
\end{figure}
```

But it will not show up. However, when I just do

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{experimentalapparatus}
```

the image shows up. The thing is, I would like to be able to use the figure environment so as to caption the figure.

I know that a similar question exists on this forum, but following those instructions didn't alleviate the problem, so clearly, something else is the matter. What's going on?

Comment: Hi and welcome, we need a bit more information. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: Do you see the caption? IS the figure on the next page?

Comment: No caption, and no, the figure is nowhere to be seen. I will try to make a minimal working example, I've never used one before!

Comment: The most important information is the document class you're using.